# Trying to override Equals method in c#

Tags: c#, casting

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextBook book1 = new TextBook();
        book1.ISBN = "0783161484100";
        book1.Title = "Horton Hears a Who";
        book1.Author = "Dr. Seus";
        book1.Price = 100.2423f;

        TextBook book2 = new TextBook();
        book2.ISBN = "0783161484100";
        Console.WriteLine(book1.Equals(book2.ISBN));
        Console.WriteLine("ISBN   :   " + book1.ISBN);
        Console.WriteLine("Title  :   " + book1.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("Author :   " + book1.Author);
        Console.WriteLine("Price  :   " + book1.Price.ToString("C"));
        Console.WriteLine("Price  :   " + book2.Price.ToString("C"));
    }
}

class Book
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public virtual float Price { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ISBN.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool result;
        Book otherBook = (Book)obj;
        if (this.ISBN == otherBook.ISBN)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class TextBook : Book
{
    public string GradeLevel { get; set; }

    float price;
    public override float Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            if (price < 20)
            {
                price = 20;
            }
            if (price > 80)
            {
                price = 80;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to overload the Equals class method but I'm getting the error `Unable to cast of type System.String to type BookDemo.Book`.

Comment: Can we see how your Customer class looks like?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information starting with the BookDemo class and its usage in your code.

Comment: `((Customer).obj)` doesn't compile.

Comment: `FirstName == (Customer)obj.FirstName...`

Comment: It is just a typo, use `book1.Equals(book2))`

Comment: What does this line do?  `Console.WriteLine(book1.Equals(book2.ISBN));`

Comment: Hans is correct, it's a typo. Also, an `Equals` method should not crash when passed an object that's not a `Book`, as yours is doing now. You should check if `otherBook is Book` and return false if not.

Comment: You shouldn't allow the hash code to ever change - so basing it on a writing property is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override method should be like:

```
public override bool Equals(Book otherBook)
    {
        bool result;
        if (this.ISBN == otherBook.ISBN)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and the usage should be:

```
Console.WriteLine(book1.Equals(book2));
```

Comment: Wow how did I not see this. Thanks a million.